# Showing the result of QTestlib with Jenkins xUnit plug-in

Tags: qt, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, qtestlib

I am trying to use Jenkins xUnit plug-in for my Qt unit test project, but I cannot make it work...

Here is What I've done so far:

First of all, I build my unit test project with qmakebuilder plug-in (providing the .pro to the qmakebuilder plug-in), then I add an `Execute Shell` build section
where I first `rm -f` the testResult xml file, following to that, I run the test binary with `-xunitxml` flag to have it generate the xml file for me And I name the xml file `testResult.xml`, in other word:

```
rm -f /home/guest/QT/unitTest/testResult.xml
cd /home/guest/QT/unitTest
./tst_unittesttest -xunitxml > testResult.xml
```

Finally in Post Build Action, I select `Publish xUnit test result` and specify the pattern as `*.xml`.

Building the job will fail though, Here is the output that I get when building the job with Jenkins:

```
[xUnit] [INFO] - Starting to record.
[xUnit] [INFO] - Processing QTestlib-Version N/A
[xUnit] [INFO] - [QTestlib-Version N/A] - 1 test report file(s) were found with
the pattern '*.xml' relative to '/home/guest/QT/unitTest' for the testing framework
'QTestlib-Version N/A'.
[xUnit] [ERROR] - The converted file for the result file '/home/guest/QT/unitTest
/testResult.xml' (during conversion process for the metric 'QTestlib') is not
valid.
The report file has been skipped.
[xUnit] [ERROR] - The plugin hasn't been performed correctly: hudson.util.IOException2:
Failed to read /home/guest/QT/unitTest/generatedJUnitFiles/QTestlib/TEST--735044756.xml
Build step 'Publish xUnit test result report' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Publish xUnit test result report' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

As you can see there is problem converting my test result xml file to what xUnit plug-in can read. My testResult.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<testsuite errors="2" failures="0" tests="4" name="UnitTestTest">
  <properties>
    <property value="4.7.4" name="QTestVersion"/>
    <property value="4.7.4" name="QtVersion"/>
  </properties>
  <testcase result="pass" name="initTestCase">
    <!-- message="called before everything else" type="qdebug" -->
  </testcase>
  <testcase result="pass" name="myFirstTest"/>
  <testcase result="pass" name="mySecondTest"/>
  <testcase result="pass" name="cleanupTestCase">
    <!-- message="called after myFirstTest and mySecondTest" type="qdebug" -->
  </testcase>
  <system-err>
<![CDATA[called before everything else]]>
<![CDATA[called after myFirstTest and mySecondTest]]>
  </system-err>
</testsuite>
```

but `TEST--735044756.xml` is an one line xml file: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Anyone has a clue where am I doing what wrong? There should be a problem with generating the output xml file.

On a different note, I have added the log thingi in the system log Jenkins menu, it doesn't seem to be the reason for this problem though... at least IMO

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Executing the test binary with `-xml` flag will just work fine. Weirdly using `-xunitxml` creates corrupt xml file which its `<testcase>` doesn't have `time` attribute. Running the test binary only with `-xml` results in building the job successfully.

Comment: I think it depends on the format you select in the configuration of the xUnit plugin. The format "QTestLib-Version N/A" (which was added in Version 1.50 of the plugin) expects QTestLib's `-xml` format.